# Select row with latest timestemp based on 3 columns using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Sample input:

| Hostnames | Status | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Host1 | Retired | 1/31/2023 9:27:06 PM |
| Host2 | Active | 2/1/2023 11:45:48 AM |
| Host1 | Active | 2/10/2023 4:59:27 AM |
| Host1 | Active | 2/13/2023 1:24:50 PM |
| Host2 | Retired | 2/10/2023 1:17:29 PM |

Now, from above table, I would like to get rows of each hostname with latest timestemp.
In above example, it should return below rows as output:

| Hostnames | Status | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Host1 | Active | 2/13/2023 1:24:50 PM |
| Host2 | Retired | 2/10/2023 1:17:29 PM |

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please add the code of your own attempt at solving the problem to the question. To get started, you may use the `Group-Object` command to group rows by `Hostnames` and use the `Sort-Object` command to sort each group by `Time`. The last element resulting from the sort will be the latest one.

Comment: If any of the given answers solves your problem, then please accept that answer so others with a similar question may find it more easily. See the [tour] on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have that data imported in a variable `$inputData`, the easiest way is to group that on property `Hostnames` first and then sort each group on the `Time` value converted to real DateTime object.

Something like this

```
$newData = $inputData | Group-Object Hostnames | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object {[datetime]$_.Time} | Select-Object -Last 1
}

# display on screen
$newData | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to csv file
$newData | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\LatestStatus.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output when displayed on screen:

```
Hostnames Status  Time                
--------- ------  ----                
Host1     Active  2/13/2023 1:24:50 PM
Host2     Retired 2/10/2023 1:17:29 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing I imported the data from CSV and then added a column with DateTime so I could sort.  See following :

```
$data = @'
"Hostnames","Status","Time"
"Host1","Retired","1/31/2023 9:27:06 PM"
"Host2","Active","2/1/2023 11:45:48 AM"
"Host1","Active","2/10/2023 4:59:27 AM"
"Host1","Active","2/13/2023 1:24:50 PM"
"Host2","Retired","2/10/2023 1:17:29 PM"
'@
$table = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv
foreach($row in $table)
{
   $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName DateTime -NotePropertyValue ([DateTime]$row.Time)
   
}
$table = $table | Sort-Object -Property DateTime -Descending
$groups = $table | Group-Object -Property HostNames
$results = $groups | foreach { $_.Group[0] }
$results
```